# Filtering out elements in an RDD with fewest entries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have an RDD of products (productID, name) and another RDD of people's ratings of those products using the MLLib Rating object (ratingTimestamp, Rating(userID, productID, rating)).

Before I do any work with those though, I want to filter out and remove products that have got less than a good amount of reviews, say 500 or so, as there are lots of products with just 1 5-star review or whatever.

I'm using this code to create a map of product IDs sorted by the number of ratings:

```
 val mostRated = ratings.map(_._2.product)
                        .countByValue
                        .toSeq
                        .sortBy(- _._2)
                        .map(_._1)
```

but this gives me every item, and I need to just filter out anything that's not got enough. I tried experimenting with the `filter()` method in the above, but couldn't figure out what to give it in order to get the result I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, just had to add this filter before the sort:

`.filter(x => x._2 > 1000)` (for 1000 reviews or more, e.g.)